# In call status bar covering navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Whenever I am on a call the green call status bar is being put on top of my navigation bar. The same applies with the hotspot status bar.

Currently using latest swift

I am guessing I need to use:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarFrame oldStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
}
```

I am not having any luck with what I need to do with it

Comment: What is your requirement ? The green bar will remain when one of the app is executing in background. You cannot get rid of that

Comment: This is by design.  What's your use case where you actually need to respond to a change in the status bar?

Comment: The green call bar is covering part of my navigation bar. I would like to move that nav bar down if possible

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with listening for frame changes in your delegate.

**First** register your view controller (or whichever class needs to adjust to the status bar frame change)

```
//
// In some class that needs to update for status bar changes
//

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(statusBarFrameWillChange:),
    name: UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification,
    object: nil)
```

**Second**, in your app delegate, add the following method (similar to your approach) to be called when the status bar is going to change

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
 willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect)
```

**Finally**, from within here you can simply post a notification to the system alerting all listening observers of this change in order to handle the status bars frame change:

```
func post(_ notification: Notification)
```

In your observer, within the `statusBarFrameWillChange` method that I chose to be called when the notification is posted, simply adjust your navigation bar's frame either down or up with respect to the status bars frame.